# Не могу справиться заданием. Assembler. NASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Вот задание:

> Напишите программу, которая будет действовать как модуль для входа в систему, то есть она сможет загружать и сохранять имя пользователя и пароль и проверять эти данные при попытке входа в систему. программа должна уметь запоминать многих пользователей. Выход из программы должен быть возможен после нажатия клавиши ESC. Используйте процедуры и стек. Должны присутствовать исключения.

Я не прошу что бы за меня что то делали, просто прошу помощи: нормальный источник изучения Assembler, NASM; идеи как можно решить это задание.

Насколько я понимаю нужно написать эту программу для ОС Windows 7 x64, и что бы ввод происходил в терминале.

Я смог написать только что бы был ввод пароля и он сверял его с правильным(который записан в коде), нужно как то сделать что бы еще был ввод логина и это все записывалось в файл и при повторном вводе сверяло при повторном вводе.

мой код:

```
    .model small
    .stack 100h
    .data
    message db ‘Enter your password:$’
    passwd  db ‘dima'
    count dw 4
    correct db ‘Password correct$’
    notcorrect db ‘Invalid password$’
.code
begin: mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov cx,count    ; cx=4
    mov bx,offset passwd ;bx переход к passwd

    ; вывод уведомления
    mov dx,offset the message
    mov ah,09
    int 21h

    ; читать символ без echo 
again:  mov ah,08   ;номер службы
    int 21h     ;читает символ в al без echo

    cmp al,[bx]
    jne error
    inc bx
    loop again

    mov dx,offset correct
    mov ah,09
    int 21h
    jmp over


error: mov dx, offset notcorrect
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

over:   mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
    end begin
```

2 вариант кода:

```
    org 100h
    .model small
    .data       msg     db « Enter your password»,0Ah,0Dh,’$’
            invalid     db « Invalid password»,0Ah,0Dh,’$’
            valid       db « Valid password»,0Ah,0Dh,’$’
            password    db «dima»,0Ah,0Dh,’$’

    .code

        lea dx,msg

        mov ah,09
        int 21h

        mov bx,offset password
        mov cx,4
        l:

        mov ah,01
        int 21h ; all

        cmp al,[bx]
        jne e
        inc bx
        loop l:

        lea dx, valid

        mov ah,09
        int 21h
        jmp exit

    e:  lea dx,invalid

        mov ah,09
        int 21h

        exit:


    ret
```

Comment: Данный ресурс предназначен для ответов на конкретные вопросы, возникающие пир написании своих программ. Но ни кто не будет писать что либо за вас

Comment: Я не прошу что бы за меня что то делали, просто прошу помощи: нормальный источник изучения Assembler, NASM; идеи как можно решить это задание.

Comment: Тогда укажите это в тексте вопроса, иначе его скоро закроют как не соответствующий тематике сайта. Дайте больше вводных, как вы поняли задание. Я например не понимаю, необходимо ли вести список пользователей на диске. Или все достаточно делать в оперативной памяти. Еще обратите внимание что приемы работы на ассемблере с любыми ресурсами операционной системы (монитор, клавиатура, диски) очень сильно на нее завязаны и необходимо искать и спрашивать про сведения касающиеся конкретной ОС.

Comment: Хорошо, получил это задание в университете без единого комментария, просто "получил задание - делай", но насколько я понимаю нужно написать эту программу для ОС Windows 7 x64, и что бы ввод происходил в терминале.

Comment: Если все только в ОЗУ то я бы выделил блок памяти под пользователей и пароли. Для простоты хранил бы все в полях фиксированной длины, скажем по 32 байта, с завершением значащих строк нулем. Программа делится на несколько частей: 1. процедура ввода строки c выводом на экран и без (или с выводом * для паролей) 2. процедура поиска пользователя по имени в массиве пользователей. 3. процедура сверки пароля. Если хотите хранить что то на диске - соответственно процедуры сохранения и чтения из файла массива пользователей (я бы писал просто блок памяти в двоичном виде, для простоты)

Comment: Хмм, интересно, можете подсказать какие материалы вы использовали/используете для изучения assembler?

Comment: Помню что моей первой книгой был "Питер Абель Ассемблер и программирование для IBM PC" было это где то начало 90х, так что другой литературы и интернета (как впрочем и Windows) не было :) А сейчас все просто, вбиваем в гугле что то вроде "nasm windows" и сразу видим настораживающие фразы, что вообще то он был сделан для unix и библиотек нормальных под windows нет. Так что в случае windows я бы наверное взял бы какой нибудь эмулятор DOS. А под DOS примеров как раз навалом, родом из тех самых 90х :)

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду отталкиваться от ваших указаний

Comment: Хотя вот например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571791/assembly-dealing-with-user-input-in-windows-nasm в ответе вывод строки на экран и получение ввода с клавиатуры под windows. Сбственно для ввода имени и пароля и вывода сообщений вроде "добро пожаловать" или "отказано в доступе" уже неплохо. Если работу с диском опустить, то все остальное уже чистый ассемблер без обращения к функциям внешнего мира

Comment: Вы значительно упростили мне задание, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Не надо использовать скриншоты для донесения текстовой информации. Пытающиеся воспроизвести вашу ситуацию будут вынуждены перепечатывать программу, и почти наверняка им будет лень это сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте в вопрос Ваш код в виде текста, а не изображения. [**Причины, почему это необходимо**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Спасибо.

Comment: изменил, добавил код

Comment: @Dmitriy, во-первых, кавычки в коде должны быть или прямые одинарные (они же апостроф `'`), или прямые двойные (`"`), но не какие-нибудь, загнутые, косые, угловые и т.д. Это первое, что не даст коду из вопроса скомпилироваться вообще. Во-вторых код из вопроса - это код для создания com файла под DOS. Под windows 7 x64 запустится только под эмулятором (например, DOS Box). Если запуск под эмулятором вас устраивает, можно поправить кавычки, и взять эти примеры за основу.

Comment: @insolor возьму на заметку по поводу кавычек, эмулятор устраивает, какой код по вашему мнение больше подходит 1 или 2?

Comment: @Dmitriy, по условию нужно использовать процедуры и стек, но в примерах кода в вопросе этого нет. Как обозначаются в nasm процедуры я не в курсе, хотя можно обойтись просто меткой и ret в конце. Стек можно использовать для передачи параметров в процедуры. Плюс, как я понимаю, раз требуется запоминание пароля, то нужна возможность работы с файлами.

Comment: @insolor робота с файлами да, что бы в начале ввести логин и пароль, записать его в файл, а потом при следующим вводе оно сверило данные и выдало сообщение верны данные или нет, не знаете как можно это реализовать?